# How can I stop the Skype notifications from re-enabling?

Tags: notifications, skype

I have Skype on my Moto G, but I don't use it much. It's primarily for contacting cow-orkers at work. I *certainly* don't want to get notified every time anyone says one in a group chat while I'm on my day off.

So I switched off the notifications by selecting "block all" in the notification settings for the app. Then I got a notification. So I switched off the notifications *again*. Then I got a notification. So I switched off the notifications *yet again*. Then... you get the picture.

**How can I *keep* the notifications from Skype switched off?**

Or do I just have to uninstall it?

Comment: I don't use Skype to test but this should work  [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) automation app. *Trigger:* Notification  Received > select Skype and configure or all *Action:*  clear notifications > clear all. *Constraints:* Day of week > select your day off. Let me know if it works fine and you want that as a solution to be posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skype running in background annoys me so much that I keep it signed OUT when not using.
To turn of notifications of SKype on Android :
Tap the **menu icon** (three vertical lines), tap **Settings** > **Notifications**, then tap **Notifications** to turn them **off**.

what you have been doing is , you were telling your android to mute the notifications its better to tell the app itself

Comment: That's indeed what I have done in the meantime. I was about to self-answer when I saw yours. Thanks.